# How would I take multiple single bit binary numbers and convert it into a single binary array number?

Tags: arithmetic, education, math-software, binary

So lets say I have these:

101010101001

Now lets also say I didn't count them you should count binary, lets say I counted that number at 6 because their are 6 1s and the 0s don't count. Now how would I convert it into this kind of binary:

011

What logic would I use to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is called (by Knuth) sideways addition, and the result is the Hamming weight (or distance from $0$) of the bit string. Knuth describes efficient methods for performing sideways addition in volume 4A of [The Art of Computer Programming](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html), 7.1.3. Bitwise Tricks and Techniques. You can find a description of some of them on the [Wikipedia page for Hamming weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight#Efficient_implementation).

The term "sideways addition" occurs (for the more general case of adding the digits in a radix $p$ representation) in a marginal note to exercise 4.24 in [Concrete Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics) by Graham, Kunth, and Patashnik (1994). I have no idea whether this is the first occurrence. By the way, the goal of that exercise is to show that the multiplicity of $p$ as prime factor in $n!$ is $$\frac{n-\nu_p(n)}{p-1}$$
where $\nu_p(n)$ is the "sideways sum" of the radix $p$ representation of $n$.

Comment: Man I've GOT to get ahold of those books and spend some time on them. Can't wait for the rest of the volumes to get published. :-)